# Why does python interpreter consider 2.0 and 2 to be the same in an when used as a dictionary key

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I was going through twitter when i came across the function below

```
def func():
    d = {1: "I", 2.0: "love", 2: "Python"}
    return d[2.0]
print(func())
```

When i ran the code, i got `Python` as the output and i expected it to be `love`. I know that you cannot have multiple key in a dictionary. However what i want to know is why Python Interpreter considers **2.0** and **2** as the same and returns the value of **2**

Comment: I expect because `hash(2) == hash(2.0)` -> `True`.

Comment: You search in a dictionary by hash then equality, `2 == 2.` too.

Comment: @snakecharmerb in fact hash was designed to guarantee that result.

Comment: To expand on @MarkRansom assertion, read the extensive notes in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/pyhash.c

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#hash) in the documentation it says that:

> Numeric values that compare equal have the same hash value (even if they are of different types, as is the case for 1 and 1.0).

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the keys `2.0` and `2` are considered the same because their hash values are equal. This is because in Python, float and integer objects can be equal even if they have different types and representations. In particular, the integer `2` and the floating-point number `2.0` have the same value, so they are considered equal.

That's why you should always use consistent types for keys in dictionaries. Always remember to use integers or floats.

Comment: What you call a bug some would call a feature.

Comment: You stated that mixing integers and floats would be a mistake.  I'm just saying there are cases where it would be useful, and riffing off an old saying about bugs and features.  See e.g. https://plainenglish.com/expressions/feature-not-a-bug/